# Faint at Heart but not really

Tags: meaning

I recently wrote something where I indicated **a technical task was not for *the faint at heart***.  What I meant to say was that the task would require a lot of technical knowledge which most of the audience would not likely have. They would need to spend time and effort to learn technical details they probably wouldn't be interested in.  So a task only undertaken by someone with the appropriate technical knowledge or someone highly motivated to learn how to do it.

Upon re-reading, I realized that some might take this as implying that if they couldn't or wouldn't do such a thing, they were in some way inadequate.

Without starting an endless debate on whether or not the expression already removes that implication, could I have put it better?  If I had been speaking, I wouldn't be concerned, but writing lacks the nuance of delivery.

Comment: “Faint of heart” refers to lack of courage, not lack of competence. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faint%20of%20heart

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I was trying to indicate it would be a daunting task for someone without a high level of technical knowledge in the area, but not impossible for someone to put in the time to work through.  I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stay with "faint-hearted" - it does not mean they can't do it, but that inspires them to try and tackle the difficult task, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Hi Tommy, welcome to English Language & Usage. Your post does answer the question to some extent, but it is more a personal opinion than the *authoritative, detailed* answer this site prefers. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Comment: And yet, it does feel better than the other suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could reword this to eliminate any "weakness" connotations.

> Repairing a jet engine by hand is not for ***the uninitiated***.
>
> Traversing a double black diamond ski slope ***requires rigorous training***.

You could also leverage idioms and exaggeration if you're writing more casually.

> Answering questions on english.stackexchange.com ***is rocket science***.

Answer (score 0):

Consider saying that it should be ***left to the experts***. Note that this can sound condescending if it *doesn't* really require rigorous training.

Here are some examples in print (emphasis, mine):

- Of course, most of the climbing in Yosemite National Park should be **left to the experts**.
  [- Wilbur H. Morrison, Adventure Guide to the Sierra Nevada](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=QdZlcmWWe9cC&pg=PA210&dq=%22left%20to%20the%20experts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFqa3yvKneAhXLtI8KHYAYCTsQ6AEILjAB)
- The question of whether the programming of such data is feasible may then be **left to the experts**.
  [- Cynthia Grabo, Handbook of Warning Intelligence](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=EeC-AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&dq=%22left%20to%20the%20experts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGvtqyvqneAhUKPI8KHVMrAMY4ChDoAQhXMAg)
- Writing such code is not as trivial as it seems, so it should be **left to the experts**.
  [- Stefan Jablonski, ‎Ilia Petrov, ‎Christian Meiler, Guide to Web Application and Platform Architectures](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Ajn-nP7IdRQC&pg=PA102&dq=%22left%20to%20the%20experts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPgKyWvqneAhVHNI8KHY8ICfU4FBDoAQg9MAM)